# Problem with listView background logic

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am using an array list, a listView, and a custom simple adapter in order to create my list in Android. In the following code, I use addItem() to add an Item. I need to add the item onActivityResult, using some of the extras I get in the intent. This all **works fine**, but the problem comes when I am trying to set the background color based on those extras that I am getting. I think it has something to do with the adapter not being refreshed, etc. My code will clear up what I am trying to say.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter;
List<HashMap<String, String>> painItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ListView listthings;
int[] to;
String[] from;
**OnCreate()**{
from = new String[] { "row_1", "row_2" };
    to = new int[] { R.id.row1, R.id.row2 };

    adapter = new Adapter(this, painItems, R.layout.mylistlayout, from, to);
            listthings.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

**Custom Adapter code**:

```
public class Adapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Adapter(Context context,
            List<? extends Map<String, String>> data, int resource,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistlayout, parent, false);
        }

        if (Integer.valueOf(painItems.get(position).get("row_3")) != null) {
            if (Integer.valueOf(painItems.get(position).get("row_3")) == 2) {
                row.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);//**BACKGROUND COLOR SET HERE**
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        return row;

    }

}
```

**How I am retrieving the necessary extras and adding the item:**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == 1) {
        row1 = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.row1");
        row2 = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.row2");
        painLevelString = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.painLevel");
        painLocation = data.getStringExtra("painLocation");
        timeOfPainString = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.painTime");
        textTreatmentString = data
                .getStringExtra("com.painLogger.treatment");
        addItem();

    }
}

// to add the item, put it in the map, and add the map into the list
private void addItem() {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("row_1", row1);
    map.put("row_2", row2);
    map.put("row_3", painLevelString);
    map.put("row_4", painLocation);
    map.put("row_5", timeOfPainString);
    map.put("row_6", textTreatmentString);
    painItems.add(map);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Again, when I add the item to my list, I want to see what the 'painlevelString' is. If it is a certain value, then I would like to set my background to a color. All the adding, etc is working, but it just ends up setting the background color to blue of whatever I add, regardless of the data I pass through the intent for that certain item.

*Although I believe I have added all the relevant code, my full activity can be found here: http://pastebin.com/4BWQYpnj.*

Thank You in advance for taking your time to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set color both if your condition is true (one color) or not (another color).

But actually I can't get where is painItems declaration in Adapter class. It seems that you meshed up two classes code

Comment: there is no declaration of painItems in Adapter class. I only have declaration in the main activity `List<HashMap<String, String>> painItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` Just as a note, all of this is in the same .java file.

Comment: I just added an else statement and it works! Great! Thank you so much for such a quick reply. what an easy fix.

Comment: could you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964036/email-intent-sends-text-file-rather-than-image? This is another problem I am encoutering